# How to use Service Accounts? Can i use my existing account at google as a service account?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

So, i have two accounts at google, one is for personal use and one for company use. At the company account i have bought drive quota and it is at 200gb (i think), so im using it as a file storage cloud-server. My idea is to implement some of the files to the company website using google drive php api. As long as i know i can [Use Application-Owned Accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts) which sounds great, BUT i have to create new account it seems in order to use it with a regular account and if i want to use it with a server-side i will be not be able to use the company files at the regular account. So, im stuck at this situation!? Please, give me some advice. This is all new to me, so i need your help.

**EDIT:**
What it says from the link i posted above is this:

> You may create a regular Google account like any user would, by going through the Google account sign-up flow or by creating an account on your Google Apps domain. **Make sure it is then never used by an actual person but only by your application.**

OK, but my account it is not new and it HAVE been used before. That mean that i will not be able to use my company account and if that is true, how can i achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally did it after days of researching how i can do this, here is a very simple code for how to obtain the access token and after you have it how to take the refresh token which you will need in order to access the user when he is in offline. I still have to understand how can i know when i store those values in the databse, how can i know that this user with the google id is the same user from the database and put the refresh token in the php, so the user dont have to authenticate again and he can do this only once (service account). So this simple code is using SESSIONS in order to store the access token and also the refresh token. It's not using database for the storage, but if you want when i figure out how this is done i can post the code here as well. So, here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Set error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
// Display errors
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// require pages, you have to change it if your pages are somewhere else!
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once "src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";
require_once "src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";

/**
 * Retrieved stored credentials for the provided user ID.
 *
 * @param String $userId User's ID.
 * @return String Json representation of the OAuth 2.0 credentials.
 */
function getStoredCredentials($userId) {
  if (!empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    return $_SESSION['userid'];
  }
}

/**
 * Store OAuth 2.0 credentials in the application's database.
 *
 * @param String $userId User's ID.
 * @param String $credentials Json representation of the OAuth 2.0 credentials to store.
 */
function storeCredentials($userId, $credentials) {
  $_SERVER['userid'] = $userId;
}

/**
 * Build a Drive service object.
 *
 * @param String credentials Json representation of the OAuth 2.0 credentials.
 * @return Google_DriveService service object.
 */
function buildService($credentials) {
  $apiClient = new Google_Client();
  $apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
  $apiClient->setAccessToken($credentials);
  return new Google_DriveService($apiClient);
}

/**
 * Send a request to the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's information.
 *
 * @param String credentials OAuth 2.0 credentials to authorize the request.
 * @return Userinfo User's information.
 * @throws NoUserIdException An error occurred.
 */
function getUserInfo($credentials) {
  $apiClient = new Google_Client();
  $apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
  $apiClient->setAccessToken($credentials);
  $userInfoService = new Google_Oauth2Service($apiClient);
  $userInfo = null;
  try {
    $userInfo = $userInfoService->userinfo->get();
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
  if ($userInfo != null && $userInfo->getId() != null) {
    return $userInfo;
  } else {
    throw new NoUserIdException();
  }
}


function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}

function printFile($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();
    print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
    print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();
  } catch (apiException $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

// fill your details from the google console:
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('***************');
$client->setScopes(array(
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
$client->setClientId('***************');
$client->setClientSecret('***************');
$client->setRedirectUri('***************/google-drive-api-php-client/serverside.php');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setDeveloperKey('***************');

// a simple code to check if the user have already login to the site and authenticate the site and if he does the site will not ask the user again for authentification and it will use the refresh token to "log" the user in
if (empty($_GET['code'])) {
    // if the user visit the website for the first time he need to authentificate (redirecting the website to google)!
    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) && !isset($_SESSION['refresh_token'])) {
        header('Location: ' . $client->createAuthUrl());
    // if the user have already visited the site, but the access token have expired use this code
    } elseif (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) && isset($_SESSION['refresh_token'])) {
        echo "refresh token1" . "<br>";
        $google_token = json_decode($_SESSION['refresh_token'], true);
        $client->refreshToken($google_token['refresh_token']);
        $_SESSION['access_token']= $client->getAccessToken();
    }
} elseif (!empty($_GET['code']) && empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    // if the user is visiting the website for the first time and dont have refresh token:
    if (!isset($_SESSION['refresh_token'])) {
        echo "access token" . "<br>";
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $_SESSION['access_token'];
      // this will never execute, but i put it anyway :) if the user have already visited the site, but the access token have expired use this code (its the same as the above)
    } elseif (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token'])) {
        echo "refresh token2" . "<br>";
        $google_token = json_decode($_SESSION['refresh_token'], true);
        $client->refreshToken($google_token['refresh_token']);
        $_SESSION['access_token']= $client->getAccessToken();
    }
}

// if the access token have expired use the refresh token to gain access instead:
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $google_token = json_decode($_SESSION['refresh_token'], true);
    $client->refreshToken($google_token['refresh_token']);
    $_SESSION['access_token']= $client->getAccessToken();
}

// unset the sessions for testing:
// unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
// unset($_SESSION['refresh_token']);

// get some info from the user Google API like the file info
if (!empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {

  // create the service in this case Google Drive
  $service = buildService($_SESSION['access_token']);
  // mark the file ID
  $fileid = "*******************";

 // print the access token
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r(getUserInfo($_SESSION['access_token']));
  echo "</pre>";

  // print file metadata from google drive
  // echo "<pre>";
  // print_r(printFile($service, $fileid));
  // echo "</pre>";


}

// printing the session for testing...
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

// print the refresh token for testing
print_r($_SESSION['refresh_token']);

// print echo to see if the code is executing till the end or there is a fatal error someone in the code :) 
echo "string";

?>
```